# не срабатывает псевдоелемент :hover так как нужно

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.block-portfolio-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
background: white;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
}

.block-portfolio-descr {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
  }


.block-portfolio-li:hover  .block-portfolio-descr{
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 25%;
}


.block-portfolio-li:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 25%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #0a88d3;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 block-portfolio block-portfolio-black-sm">
        <div class="block-portfolio-li">
            <span class="block-portfolio-descr">
              <div class="block-portfolio-circle">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x color-black" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 37%"></i>
              </div>
            </span>
            <img src="1.png"  class="img-responsive ">
        </div>
        <div class="block-portfolio-number center">
            <h1 class="block-portfolio-number-style">1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 block-portfolio block-portfolio-black-sm">
        <div class="block-portfolio-li">
            <span class="block-portfolio-descr">
              <div class="block-portfolio-circle">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x color-black" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 37%"></i>
              </div>
            </span>
            <img src="2.png"  class="img-responsive ">
        </div>
        <div class="block-portfolio-number center">
            <h1 class="block-portfolio-number-style">2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Есть код, проприсал классы в CSS, при наведении должно происходить следующее:

```
- появляться снизу кружок белого цвета
- увеличиваться картинка
- картинка закрашиваться должна полупрозрачным голубым цветом
```

результат кода:

```
- элемент .block-portfolio-circle появляется
- картинка увеличивается , но НЕ обрезается (overflow: hidden не срабатывает почему то)
- при наведении делается только полупрозрачным, цвет не изменяется
```

Подскажите, что я НЕ так делаю?где я ошибся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб картинка обрезалась `overflow: hidden` должен быть не на ней, а на ее родительском элементе. А закрашивание не происходило, так как Вы меняли `background` родителя - он-то и становился синим, но на саму картинку это никак не влияло.

```css
.block-portfolio-li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.block-portfolio-descr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block-portfolio-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 40px);
  top: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.block-portfolio-li:hover .block-portfolio-descr {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #0a88d3;
}

.block-portfolio-li:hover .block-portfolio-circle {
  top: 20%;
}

.block-portfolio-li:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 block-portfolio block-portfolio-black-sm">
      <div class="block-portfolio-li">
        <span class="block-portfolio-descr">
          <div class="block-portfolio-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x color-black" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 37%"></i>
          </div>
        </span>
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/300/150"  class="img-responsive ">
      </div>
      <div class="block-portfolio-number center">
        <h1 class="block-portfolio-number-style">1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 block-portfolio block-portfolio-black-sm">
      <div class="block-portfolio-li">
        <span class="block-portfolio-descr">
          <div class="block-portfolio-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x color-black" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 37%"></i>
          </div>
        </span>
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/302/150"  class="img-responsive ">
      </div>
      <div class="block-portfolio-number center">
        <h1 class="block-portfolio-number-style">2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а то я чуть с ума не сошел!